# invoking a flex application from android when SMS comes

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, android-emulator, flex4.5

i have developed an application in flex.I want to invoke this application when an SMS comes comes to my android mobile. Please help  me.

Comment: Do some research and come with clear idea

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
This is probably what you'll need

put the following in your androidmanifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"> 
     <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
     </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

And use this code to handle whatever action you want when receiving an SMS

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{ 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

I dont have any experience with flex on android, so there may be some differences

Comment: can u please send some sample code to solve the above problem